# Can not uninstall docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Sorry if this is obvious, I'm new to docker.
I forgot how I installed docker-compose, so I tried:

```
$ which docker-compose
/snap/bin/docker-compose
```

I tried to uninstall it via snap:

```
$ sudo snap remove docker-compose
snap "docker-compose" is not installed
$ sudo rm -r docker-compose
rm: cannot remove 'docker-compose': No such file or directory
```

But here's the problem:

```
docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.5, build unknown
```

It seems that docker-compose is still somewhere in the system, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you did install it through apt, a

```
sudo apt remove docker-compose
```

would remove docker-compose from your system

Comment: I think I install it via snap

Comment: A `sudo snap remove docker-compose` should probably be the command to remove it.